# \emph breaks soul's underline

Tags: nesting, soul, emphasis, underline

`\emph` within `soul`'s `\ul` leaves small gaps in the underline, their size varying depending on the font and whether there is a space after `\emph`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}


\ul{a \emph{b} c}

%smaller
\ul{a\emph{b}c}

%tiny
\textsf{\ul{a \emph{b} c}}

%canceled
\ul{a \emph{b{\kern-.01em}} c}

\ul{a \emph{b }c}


\end{document}
```

It can be avoided by adding a kern or by moving the space, but this is quite impractical in real-life texts.

Is there any way to avoid the breaking of the line in these cases globally?

Comment: It concerns the italic correction..Compare `\ul{a {\itshape b} c}` and `\ul{a \textit{b} c}`.

Comment: See the documentation, page 14. You must set the italic correction explicitly: `\ul{a \emph{b\/} c}`.

Comment: Thanks, I've found it now. But I don't understand it nonetheless: `a \emph{b\/} c` and `a \emph{b} c` are rendered completely identical in LaTeX (with Plain TeX there is a clear difference between `a {\it b} c` and `a {\it b\/} c`) -- can you explain what is happening here? And ideally how I get around it? I would have a lot of these cases to correct manually otherwise…